# Small data relocation error when linking, trying to read from stack

Tags: c, pointers, linker, embedded, linker-errors

I am currently trying to implement a functionality for which I need to read values from stack memory locations.
I am doing this by getting the address "__CPU_STACK" as an external, it is defined in the linker script.
When building I am getting this error message: `Small data relocation against an object not in a named small data section [...] symbol name = __CPU_STACK` from the linker. I do not know about small data, I have been trying to look it up but to no avail. Also I could not find an error definition for this.

This is a short version of my call:

```
extern uint32 __CPU_STACK;

uint32* core1_stackHighAddress = (uint32*) __CPU_STACK;

boolean expected_value =  (PREDEFINED_VALUE == *(stack_lowAddress));
```

Can anyone tell me what this error means? Maybe where I need to look?

My current guess is that I am not allowed to read this memory location, since I am running a user function with an embedded OS in the background.

Comment: Error messages from the linker are toolchain specific.  What toolchain are you using?

Comment: What does the linker script look like - that is more important here than the code. "_short version of my call:_"  what call? There is no "call".  Did you mean "code"?  What are those weird `uint32` types?  Did you mean `uint32_t`.  You need to post _real_ code that you _know_ exhibits the actual problem, not pseudo-code that _resembles_ your actual code.  It need not be the code you found the problem on, but it should be the minimum comparable code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Most embedded RTOS do not use MMU protection and in any case that would result in a runtime error not a linker error, so that hypothesis is unlikely.  That said what OS _are_ you using.  It may be relevant.

Comment: Also specify the target.  "small data" may relate specifically to PowerPC architecture - is that what you are using?  You could loose some of those more generic tags and replace them with something more useful and specific to your problem.

Comment: What was in the elided section `[...]` ? Diagnostic messages are more useful in their entirety.  Presumably that is not the only output from the linker?  You are probably not in a position to determine what we need to see so it is easier to provide _everything_, even if you think it is irelevant.

Comment: Also note that if you OS is multi-threaded, each thread will have its own stack in any case, so the __CPU_STACK may be irrelevant and may only be used before the scheduler starts and/or for interrupts.